# Unresolved reference GoogleSignIn

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm getting "Unresolved reference" for GoogleSignIn

The current files set up:

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':signin:app'
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {

ext{
    kotlin_version = '1.2.60'
    lifecycle_version = '1.1.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }
}
}
```

app gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
...}
```

and finally import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
```

I tried to rebuild Project, Refresh Gradle Projects and Invalidate caches and I still get Unresolved reference for GoogleSignIn.
When I tried to change play-services-gcm:**15.0.1**' to play-services-gcm:**16.0.0**', which is the newest Google Account Login, I get an error: "Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0". 
Installing repository and sync projects gives another error "Could not find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"

Gradle version 4.4
Android Plugin Version 3.1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not implement all google play services in your project for use only auth service

The size of the Apk file will increase, so replace the dependency as below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

And it is advisable update google-services Plugin Version to 4.0.2